# How do I remove the vertex border in mxGraph?

Tags: javascript, stroke, mxgraph

I'm trying to get it so that a vertex will highlight a border on a mouse over, but have no border otherwise. I've tried using the strokewidth and stroke color to do this, but the border doesn't seem to obey me setting it to zero, there's always a 1px outline.

Looking at the source code I have I see:

```
var strokeWidth=Math.max(1,this.strokewidth*this.scale);
```

So should I override this and remove the Math.max call so the 1px minimum isn't enforced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Chrome ignores the value 0 for stroke-widths (uses 1). Try using

```
strokeColor=none
```

The [API specification](http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/util/mxConstants-js.html#mxConstants.STYLE_STROKEWIDTH) is worth reading when facing such problems.